# is select distinct().count() is a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark

I saw the

```
df.select(“name”).distinct().count() <br/>
```

is this pyspark data frame? or pandas data frame?

Answer (score 0):

count() is an action in spark so you will get back the count of the spark data frame.

FYI, select and distinct are the transformations which will give you back the data frame. As spark follows lazy evaluation, no computation (in most cases) in spark happens until you call action.

Comment: @dailygirlflower please accept the answer if this is what you were looking for